# R Plot - Y Axis and plotted values are not the same (values from txt file)

Tags: r, plot

I am somewhat new to R and I am trying to plot values from real data .
x axis is the time and y axis real values but in graph y axis  is between 0 and 100, but the real values of y are different.

I need your help.Thank you

Comment: `data <- read.table("data.txt") y <- data$V1 t <- c(1:100) plot(t,y) lines(t,y)` this is my code

Comment: Please provide us with an [example of your data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2005219)

Comment: my data just contain one column : 9,12368
8,90582
8,92218
8,53934
7,99324
7,53952
7,51255
7,1065
6,91431
6,9704
7,92692
7,74947
7,10618
6,50479
5,9741
5,08136
4,32405
3,86809
3,4377
3,54596
3,07406
2,92242
1,67285
1,11221
0,501673

Comment: If your data in file have comma as decimal separator then in function `read.table()` add argument `dec=","`.

Comment: [This a capture of data imported into Rstdio](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaAyD.gif)

Comment: Replace your values with . use gsub function data$V1<- gsub(",",".", data$V1)

Comment: Now it works ,thank you very much

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12487292)

Answer (score 0):

```
y <- c(9.21368, 8.90582, 8.92218, 8.53934, 7.99324, 7.53952, 7.51255, 7.1065, 6.91431,
       6.9704,  7.92692, 7.74947, 7.10618, 6.50479, 5.9741, 5.08136, 4.32405, 3.86809, 
       3.4377, 3.54596, 3.07406, 2.92242, 1.67285, 1.11221, 0.501673)
t <- 1 : length(y)
plot(t, y)

# Length(y) and length(t) must be same.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, like that it works but when I read y values from txt file I can't get the same result , y axis can't dispaly real values !

Answer (score 0):

The y-axis is always like the x axis but in reality is not like that:

[image: the y-axis is always like the x axis but in reality is not like that]

Answer (score 0):

```
You can view your y-axis values in the plot, by adding text function

    y <- c(9.21368, 8.90582, 8.92218, 8.53934, 7.99324, 7.53952, 7.51255, 7.1065, 6.91431,
           6.9704,  7.92692, 7.74947, 7.10618, 6.50479, 5.9741, 5.08136, 4.32405, 3.86809, 
           3.4377, 3.54596, 3.07406, 2.92242, 1.67285, 1.11221, 0.501673)
    t <- 1: length(y)
    plot(t,y)
    text(t,y,pos=3, cex=0.7)
```

[image]

Comment: when I read y values from txt file, y-axis can't show real values, it gives me graph like that  http://i.stack.imgur.com/Occhh.png